CLion / Pycharm: how to easily run & debug a file as a module
I'm using CLion (which is close to Pycharm as far as Python is concerned).
I know that it is possible to run and debug modules within these IDEs. However the usage is cumbersome compared to running/debugging python files:

With a Python file you can simply right click and select run.
This configuration for a script was created automatically via "Right-click/Run"


In order to run the same file as a module, we are back to full manual mode. The configuration below had to be created manually, and then I had to tediously enter the module name (which is almost the python file name, minus some mechanical adjustments).



Since the transformation is so mechanical, is there a better way (that would allow the same ease of use for run & debugging), or there a plugin/tool I could add?
